# Is there any way to generate a pivot table in Google Sheets using only formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I got stuck on a task to generate a pivot table in Google Sheets without actually using a 'Pivot table' tool.

Export file with raw data:

[image: raw data]

The goal is to generate a sheet based on this export file, where all the tasks will be grouped by the project, and to calculate time totals for every project.

My goal is this:

[image: goal]

The problem is that the number of projects and tasks is not constant, so the number of rows for every project may vary.

I know that there's a 100% working solution to generate a Pivot table using the native tool, but my goal is to do that by using only formulas or script. Is there any way?

Here's the actual sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfeGbOOe7KVa0E4OlkZ9PMhM6xGoXaQVx4Yx7sU3qZU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY("♠"&SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")))&
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(A2:C,
 "select B,sum(C) where B<>'' group by B pivot A", 0), "offset 1", 0)), "offset 1", 0)), 
 "♠ ♦"&TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))))&"♦"&QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(A2:C,
 "select B,sum(C) where B<>'' group by B pivot A", 0), "offset 1", 0)), "offset 1", 0), ))
 , , 999^99))&"♠ ♦Total:♦"&MMULT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(A2:C,
 "select B,sum(C) where B<>'' group by B pivot A", 0), "offset 1", 0)), "offset 1", 0)*1,
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)&"♦", COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)), "♦")^0)), , 999^99)), 
 "♠")), "♦"); "", "Total:", SUM(C2:C)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A,B,count(C) where B <> '' group by A,B")
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't even come to my mind that it's possible to group by several columns at the same time. I just replaced 'count' with 'sum' and now it's almost what I wanted. The goal is to calculate time totals for every project as well.